# Linear Algebra proof question about dimension of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing Q1(c)(ii)

I've shown in (c)(i) that $\{v_1, v_2, ... , v_{n-2}, v_{n-1}+t v_n\}$ is a basis of $W_t$.
So would it be correct saying that $W_t \cap W_s$ has basis $\{v_1, v_2, ... , v_{n-2}\}$ if $t \neq s$ straight away?

If not, what would I need to show?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the intersection contains those $n-2$ vectors, and they're independent; that shows that the intersection has dimension at *least* $n-2$. And it has dimension at most $n-1$, because it's a subspace of $W_t$, whose dimension is $n-1$.

The problem is that you need to show that its dimension is at *most* $n-1$. One way to do this is to show that there's a vector in $W_t$ that's not in the intersection; then the intersection is a *proper* subspace, and hence has lower dimension. (That uses a theorem, but it's probably one that you have on hand). Can you think of an element of $W_t$ that's not in $W_s$ (and prove that it's not)?

To answer the question you asked directly ("Would I be correct..."), I'd say, "No, there's a bit more to do."

Addition following comment discussion:

I'm going to assume you know the following lemma, or could prove it; if not, ping me back:

Lemma: If $A \subset B$ is a proper subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $B$, then the dimension of $A$ is less than the dimension of $B$.

Let $U = W_t \cap W_s$.

We already know that $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{n-2}\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $U$, hence $dim( U) \ge n-2$; and since $U \subset W_t$, we know $dim (U) \le n-1$.

With the lemma in mind, we can show that $dim (U) < dim (W_t) = n-1$ by simply showing that there's a vector $v$ in $W_t$ that's not in $U$. As you guessed in the comments, $v = v_{n-1} + tv_n$ is a good candidate.

How can we show that $v \notin U = W_s \cap W_t$ ? We know that $v \in W_t$, so we'll have to show that $v \notin W_s$.

How do you do that?

You *assume* that $v$ *is* in $W_s$ and arrive at a contradiction. The contradiction, in this case, will be that $s$ turns out to equal $t$, which we assumed was false. Let's go for it.

Suppose $v \in W_s$. Then $v$ is in the span of the set defining $W_s$, i.e., $v$ can be written as a linear combination
$$
v = a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_{n-2} v_{n-2} + a_{n-1} (v_{n-1} + s v_n).
$$
Now recalling the definition of $v$, that means that 
$$
v_{n-1} + t v_n = a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_{n-2} v_{n-2} + a_{n-1} (v_{n-1} + s v_n).
$$

Rearranging terms, we get
$$
0 = a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_{n-2} v_{n-2} + (a_{n-1} - 1) v_{n-1} + (a_{n-1}s - t) v_n.
$$

Now the set $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is linearly independent, and we've got a linear combination of those vectors that turns out to be zero, hence the coefficients must all be zero. In particular, the second-to-last one must be zero, so $a_{n-1} = 1$. And the last one must also be zero, so $s - t = 0$, so $s = t$. That's a contradiction.

Comment: I see. If I choose a vector $a(v_{n-1} + t v_n)$ in $W_t$, the only way this can be written as a linear combination of elements of basis of $W_s$ is if $t = s$. Is this correct?

Comment: No @user120227, not quite. See my additional remarks in the comment above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)